# Synchronization between SQLLite on Android device and SQL Server database using Microsoft Sync

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, sqlite, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to Synchronize between SQLLite on Android device and SQL Server database using Microsoft Sync? The official microsoft site says it is possible, but no samples or other documents are presented in this issue. Does any one where can I find a sample to use, or this issue is still not supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there's no built-in database provider in Sync Framework for SQLLite.

have a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e), there are samples there on how to write a client provider that can sync with  SQL Server at the back end.